# RSA encryption calls hang on windows Virtual Machines

Tags: windows, virtual-machine, encryption, rsa

We moved to BouncyCastle FIPS version 1.0.1 and since then RSAKeyHelper hangs for extended periods of time in Windows VMs (stack below).

We had a similar issue in Linux that was solved by increasing entropy (urandom/haveged/etc.)

Is there a similar workaround that can be employed for the Windows environment?

```
Daemon Thread [http-bio-18080-exec-10] (Suspended)  
                    owns: Object  (id=2939) 
                    owns: Boolean  (id=2940)             
                    owns: SocketWrapper<E>  (id=117)          
                    SHA2$SHA256(SHA2).implDigest(byte[], int) line: 98         
                    SHA2$SHA256(DigestBase).engineDigest(byte[], int, int) line: 181               
                    SHA2$SHA256(DigestBase).engineDigest() line: 160          
                    MessageDigest$Delegate.engineDigest() line: 592              
                    MessageDigest$Delegate(MessageDigest).digest() line: 365          
                    ManifestEntryVerifier.verify(Hashtable<String,CodeSigner[]>, Hashtable<String,CodeSigner[]>) line: 207  
                    JarVerifier.processEntry(ManifestEntryVerifier) line: 241 
                    JarVerifier.update(int, byte[], int, int, ManifestEntryVerifier) line: 228       
                    JarVerifier$VerifierStream.read(byte[], int, int) line: 482  
                    URLClassPath$JarLoader$2(Resource).getBytes() line: 124             
                    Launcher$ExtClassLoader(URLClassLoader).defineClass(String, Resource) line: 462              
                    URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader, String, Resource) line: 73    
                    URLClassLoader$1.run() line: 368               
                    URLClassLoader$1.run() line: 362               
                    AccessController.doPrivileged(PrivilegedExceptionAction<T>, AccessControlContext) line: not available [native method]              
                    Launcher$ExtClassLoader(URLClassLoader).findClass(String) line: 361       
                    Launcher$ExtClassLoader(ClassLoader).loadClass(String, boolean) line: 424            
                    Launcher$ExtClassLoader(ClassLoader).loadClass(String) line: 357              
                    BouncyCastleFipsProvider.<init>(String, SecureRandom) line: not available            
                    BouncyCastleFipsProvider.<init>(String) line: not available             
                    BouncyCastleFipsProvider.<init>() line: not available        
                    RSAKeyHelper.<init>(String, String) line: 35
```

Comment: Lack of entropy should not be a problem with Win32 Crypto API calls: https://serverfault.com/a/408673/174582 Though I suppose it's possible that BouncyCastle is doing something weird...

Comment: Thanks for the answers, it is a FIPS compliant library so it must make sure that it gets quality random input, might be coming from that direction.